# Problema para visualizar correctamente los datos de una gráfica en Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

después de un largo tiempo volví a retomar Python y actualmente me encuentro replicando unos datos con Matplotlib a partir de la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Figura 3(a), ejemplo]

El código es el siguiente:

```
x_1=[0.000,100.943,150.943,201.887,250.943,350.000]
y_1=[0.000,28.135,56.269,85.933,99.388,100.000]

plt.xlim(0,400)
plt.ylim(0,100)

plt.title('(a)')

plt.ylabel('Elimnación de TPHs (%)')
plt.xlabel('Temperatura (°C)')

for pos in ['right', 'top']: 
    plt.gca().spines[pos].set_visible(False)

plt.plot(x_1,y_1,'ok-', markersize=15)

plt.show()

plt.savefig('3.1 (a).png')
```

Al correr el código me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los datos de la gráfica no se vean 'cortados' sin tener que cambiar los límites? y ¿Cómo puedo escalar el eje x para que esté de 100 en 100 con todos los números?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que los datos de la gráfica no se vean 'cortados' sin tener que cambiar los límites?

Establece `clip_on=False` como argumento de `plt.plot`:

```
plt.plot(x_1, y_1, 'ok-', markersize=15, clip_on=False)
```

##### ¿Cómo puedo escalar el eje x para que esté de 100 en 100 con todos los números?

Utiliza `plt.xticks` y establece los valores que quieres plotear. En este caso, desde 0 hasta 400 con incremento de 100:

```
plt.xticks(range(0, 401, 100))
```

De manera equivalente utilizando `numpy`:

```
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 400 + 1, 100))
```

Comment: Buena respuesta! Solo una cosa. No sería mejor usar `list(range(...))` en lugar de una comprensión de listas del estilo `[i for i in range(...)]`?

Comment: @DanteS. realmente se ve mejor como lo pones, pero bueno, ya es cuestión de gustos. Al final hacen lo mismo. De todas las formas prefiero usar numpy.

Comment: Es entendible. Numpy es más rapido. Aun así, si puedes tener el objeto range sin convertir a otra secuencia te podrías ahorrar mucha memoria. Esto se debe a que range solo guarda start, stop y step y va calculando los numeros intermedios según es necesario.

Comment: Bueno, de hecho, acabo de leer que `plt.xticks` acepta como argumento cualquier Iterable, por tanto, lo mejor sería `plt.xticks(range(0, 401, 100))`. Lo probé y funciona perfectamente. La diferencia de lo que me proponías `list(range(...))` y `[i for i in range(...)]` es puramente cosmética, no hay diferencia de rendimiento ahí. Ahora poniendo solamente `range` si la hay, ya que no hay que generar la lista.